# Alternative Notifications System than Javascript setInterval with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I built a notification system that checks whether there are new notifications every 10 seconds using the `setInverval` javascript function, that sends ajax request and returns a json with the notifications.

I would like to hear alternative ways to do that, that doesn't have to be timed.

Is a while loop & a worker thread better?
Since I'm working with PHP, how do I not overload the server with too many requests?

What are the security risks I am facing with my system, and with the system you'd like to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not satisfied with your current mechanism, look into the cluster of various mechanisms collectively called "[comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)" and/or [web sockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) depending on the browser profiles you have to support ([IE8 and 9 don't have web sockets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets), for instance). There are several libraries out there to help you with this, such as [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

I don't think the security profile changes either way, but that would probably be a separate question in any case.

Comment: Does php support sockets?

Comment: @JacobCohen: :-) A quick search for "php websocket" turned up [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/), [`phpwebsocket`](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/), and this SO question and its answers: [*How to create websockets server in PHP*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512182).

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like both are working on the same idea.
Client sends a request to the Server, and gets an answer and decides what to do with it.

I need the client to keep listening to the server, and when the server sends a message, the client will do what it wants with it.

Still reading about socket.io, it might be doing what I need.

Comment: @JacobCohen: What makes you think that? From the [Ratchet "Process Flow" page](http://socketo.me/docs/flow): *"...once the webpage has been loaded a WebSocket connection is made back to your Ratchet application, where if everything goes correctly, a connection remains open where either the server or client can send data to the other one at any given time."*

Comment: @JacobCohen: Re socket.io, most of what you'll find is based on a NodeJS backend, but if you search around, there are PHP projects for socketio backends in PHP. I don't know how good they are, never having had to use one.

Comment: Oh, I might have briefed it too much.

I'll read more carefully.