# How to get the value in javascript into php to store in SQL?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("latitude");
var y = document.getElementById("longitude");
function getLocation() 
{
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        y.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
}

function showPosition(position) 
{
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude;
    y.innerHTML = "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

I need to store the X and Y value in variable in the data in SQL database and also display inside the php.

Comment: send the request vars via post or get

Comment: either send a form or make an AJAX call

Comment: AJAX request or a simple hidden html element submitted through a form either through a get or a post method. Moreover, remember to sanitize that value before querying it inside your database.

Comment: i tried via post and get. i can't get the value..

Comment: can plz say how to do hidden html element for this@briosheje

Comment: @SparkyBuddy: Show us the post and get attempts you did, I recommend you to include the relevant javascript part relative to that and, if possible, even the relevant php part.

Answer (score 1):

Send an Ajax request to your php file.

```
var x = document.getElementById("latitude");
var y = document.getElementById("longitude");
jQuery.ajax({
        url:  "path/to/file/script.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            lat:x,
            lng:y
        },
        success:function(data){

        },
        error: function(err){
            jQuery('.errorText').fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

Then handle values in php with $_POST['lat'] and $_POST['lng'], and query your php script to insert data to db , with mysql or mysqli.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO locations(lat, lng)
VALUES (".$_POST['lat'].", ".$_POST['lng'].")";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: url:  "path/to/file/script.php",

Comment: this is a path to your php file, where do you save your php file. If it is in tha same directory as your jquery file, then just write a "script.php", if no, eg. it is located in /php/scripts.php u need to write that url

Comment: U can do it separatly or in php, whatever u want, if you will add it separatly, u need to include the script into your html head or in php file.

Comment: my doubt is were i need to put the this jQuery.ajax({ ... code

Comment: i want to add the Jquery code with PHP tag or inside the the script tag

Comment: no matter where you will add it, if u want to add it to php file, go ahead, the only thing you need to do right, is that  you should give a path to your php file, jquery ajax should know where exactly send the request

Answer (score 0):

Well, JavaScript lives in the browser of the user, and PHP/SQL on the backend (in your control I presume).

This means you need to somehow submit those values to the backend. Three most common ways of doing so:

- Via an API (i.e. REST API) using AJAX ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567149/782609))
- Via a WebSocket connection ([discussion on how to do that in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512182/how-to-create-websockets-server-in-php))
- By submitting a form ([PHP manual for handling a form](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php))

Then, handle such a request in PHP code and store the values in the database.

Comment: @Daan - Actually the first bullet is an AJAX, I just updated an answer to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to pass the value and insert in the database. If you don't want to use ajax then you can store the value of latitude and longitude in the hidden type using the javascript. and then onsubmit pass the value of the hidden type and insert the value in the database.

```
var latitude = document.getElementById("latitude").value;
var longitude = document.getElementById("longitude").value;
var datastring = 'latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude ; // get data in the form manual 
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // type
            url:"ajax.php", // request file the 'check_email.php'
            data: datastring, // post the data
            async: false,
            success: function(responseText) { // get the response

            } // end success
    }).responseText; // ajax end
```

In the ajax file you can get the value of the latitude and longitude by `$_POST['latitude']` and `$_POST['longitude']` and then use that value to insert it into the database.

Comment: from where the ajax.php comes form.

Comment: You have to make a new file with the name ajax.php and then make a database call in that file and get the value which you want to store in the database.