# dose JQuery is fastest way to listen to mysql for new record or load new content with clicking?

Tags: php, jquery, comet

1- I've developed a web-based support messaging system for my users.(not chat - something like facebook messsage system). the system listen to mysql every 10 second for check new message.

do you think I must use JQuery or Comet or anything else?

2- also I want load more content automaticly(with click on a button or scrolling to end of page). Dose JQuery is only fast method to do that?

this a sample website that I developed it: [wepars](http://www.wepars.com)

It loads more content automaticly with JQuery but sometimes auto load content do not works well. I think it is too slow when I compare with some other website!

---

Ofcoure I heard about nodejs but I think it is too complex for programming and also it is for reatime chat so I do not need that for this type of project. what do you think? Am I right?

I work with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is simple and stable for things like that.
If you want to make your script faster, you may use pure JavaScript, XMLHttpRequest is your solution.

And I think you mixed meanings of server and client side technologies in your question.

Comment: I know nodejs is a server side js. but everyone suggest me use that for realtime chat!...so you recommend me using jquery or pure js...right? and I do not need anything else? what about Comet? I did not use it. but I think The use of this method is for question 1.

Comment: Nothing can be faster than a pure code. Enable compression and caching on your server, and everything will be ok! Comet is a model, not library by the way. You can also use WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

I guess using jQuery it's ok. As was mentioned, pure JS is faster, but it makes you write more code and it is less clear. You always make a choice from speed and convinient. If jQuery is too slow for you in some places, you can use pure JS. Also, if your chat system needs to get push changes in time it was made, you need to use WebSockets instead of pooling. You can find realizations of WebSockets on php [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512182/how-to-create-websockets-server-in-php). But general idea php is meant to die, so i guess it will be more convinient to don't use it as continuous running application.