# AJAX Real-time live notification

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have been using setInterval(function(), ms) everytime I am making a live notification feature in my website but is there any alternative way to make this live notification without sending request every 5 or 10 seconds, depends on what interval you set. Isn't it heavy to send post/get request everytime you need new datas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it would take a lot of bandwidth. for solution: you can either use `WebSocket` technology or the `Long Polling` method ..

[Click here](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/) for `Long Polling` reference.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512182/how-to-create-websockets-server-in-php) for `Web Socket` reference.