# PHP Live Update (Like OpenCAD)

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if it is possible to live update PHP without AJAX, JS, jQuery and so on, only with clean PHP?

Comment: PHP is a server-only language. to update the PHP content on the page, the server has to generate it, and the client will reload the page. Eventually with AJAX you don't have to reload the page.

Comment: Okay, then I will need to read up on AJAX. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for real-time transmission in phpn that names: "websockets".

That is like: http://socketo.me/demo

And here is more about the thema: [How to create websockets server in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512182/how-to-create-websockets-server-in-php)