# How to update data from database in realtime?

Tags: flutter

I will build an app where I fetch data from http. 
The backend is PHP and on the page it show me the phpmyadim database.

In flutter I would like to get the data and show it in a listview. And when the data is change I would like that the listview is automatically reloaded.

My question is should I use Future builder or stream builder? And how I should do it.

Answer (score 3):

WebSockets is a good choise when your data changes very frequently for example during chat session. Otherwise I propose to use Firebase Cloud Messaging it will give you online data update when your app is open and push notification if it's close.

In your root widget

```
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
           // or use setState
          _bloc.dispatch(new LoadMyCalendar());
        }
    );
```

Second part is call Firebase API from your web server app when data is changing

Comment: We use this and it works really well for iOS, Android, Web, Flutter. Also you can turn off push notifications optionally.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update the data in realtime with HTTP requests. Only sockets can allow realtime comunication. You need to use websocket in this case. These might help:

[Websockets in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512182/how-to-create-websockets-server-in-php)

[Websockets in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets)

Comment: Just a note, web sockets are really horrible at scale.

Comment: @OliverDixon is there any better solutions available?

Comment: Firestore does everything.

Comment: Yeah, best solution.