# PHP MySQL : How to make an auto refresh data only when data changed on database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter-3

Usually I make content refresh automatically with the javascript function using setInterval.
But it seems ineffective because every second the content must be reloaded will take up a lot of resources.

Therefore if there is another alternative to creating an automatic refresh function only when the data has changed in the database.

Comment: Integrate `websocket` in php and listen for changes in `javascript` and refresh on changes Ref: [Websockets in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512182/how-to-create-websockets-server-in-php)

Comment: Thank you for your alternative solution. Maybe i am newbie :(  need an example simple project which is integrated with the mysql database.

Comment: If the resources are at the database layer, include `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` and the SQL to retrieve it. What would the SQL be to retrieve the changes? How are database changes occuring and could you use a websocket to pipe raw new results from whatever changes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to update your data would be to use Ajax in the frontend to request the data every few seconds and update it instead of reloading the page. Otherwise, you should check out `socket.io` (websockets)