# Websockets encoding data to be send

Tags: php, websocket

I'm trying to encode the data that I will send to the browser using websockets. I base myself on [this tutorial](http://srchea.com/blog/2011/12/build-a-real-time-application-using-html5-websockets/):

```
private function encode($text) {
    // 0x1 text frame (FIN + opcode)
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCS', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCN', $b1, 127, $length);

    return $header.$text;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this function because I'm not getting any data in web browser.
I use it on this line:

```
    $msg = $this->encode($msg);

    parent::send($client,$msg);
```

PS: I'm not good with binary actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used that same code originally to encode data in my WebSocket script, and it won't work in some cases even with your corrections.
The problem is that the length of the payload (data) is not properly calculated. In other words, you can't just use the strlen function.

Please see my related post for details on how to fix this: [What is this data at the end of WebRTC candidate info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425382/what-is-this-data-at-the-end-of-webrtc-candidate-info)

Comment: I don't understant how you get the length of the message? What is the character at position 1 telling you about the lenght if the message is a plain string?

Comment: The character at position 1 (i.e., the second byte of the message) is a combination of one bit denoting whether the message is masked (i.e., encoded) and seven bits denoting the payload (i.e., data) length. The first bit must always be 1 according to the specs because the message must always be masked. The next seven bits when converted to a decimal give you the length. However, because you can only go up to 127 with seven bits, there must be a way of getting the length of messages that are longer than that. According to the specs, if the message is longer than 125 characters...

Comment: Then the seven bits marking the payload length must be 126, and the actual length is then stored in the 3rd and 4th bytes in the message. If the message is longer than 65,535 characters, then the seven bits marking the payload length must be 127, and the actual length is stored in the 3rd through 8th bytes. In order to convert the binary bits that make up the bytes into a decimal for the length, you have to use the bitwise operators as I have done in the solution linked above...

Comment: And in order to get the length stored in the last seven bits of the 2nd byte in the message, you need to use logical AND (i.e., the & operator) to essentially ignore the 1 set for the first bit used to denoted whether the message is masked or not. For details on how data is framed, please see the [official WebSocket specs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17#section-5.2). Also, if you need info on what bitwise operators are and how to use them in PHP, please see the following: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: So what your saying is that all strings have this header already or I need to create this header?

Comment: @Dharman, all strings sent from the client to the server have a header, which must be parsed and stripped away in order to properly unmask the payload. When you're ready to forward the payload to one or more other clients, you must then create a new (and different) header, attach that header to the front of the payload, and forward the header + payload.

Answer (score 2):

Dharman's corrected if statements fail for strings over 125 characters. The correct if statements are:

```
    if($length <= 125) {
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    } elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536) {
        $header = pack('CSC', $b1, 126, $length);
    } elseif ($length >= 65536) {
        $header = pack('CNC', $b1, 127, $length);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, Brandon. You are right that my if statements are wrong, they were wrong when I copied them from the tutorial. I am planning to take my tutorial down, because it is no longer correct and full of mistakes. I can't even remember this SO question and didn't know it was here. :) However if you would like to correct it for future readers, please include explanation of your fix.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The if statements were wrong. That's how they should look like:

```
    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCS', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCN', $b1, 127, $length);
```

Comment: This fails for strings over 125 characters. The correct code is:

`
    if($length <= 125) {
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    } elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536) {
        $header = pack('CSC', $b1, 126, $length);
    } elseif ($length >= 65536) {
        $header = pack('CNC', $b1, 127, $length);
    }
`